# How do I make the companyWebsite fetch show up on my browser as a clickable link

Tags: javascript

I'm fetching company data such as the logo, company title, description and website. When the website comes through, it is a regular text string. I would like it to show up on the browser as a clickable link.

```
function getCompanyProfile(symbol) {
  const url = `https://.appspot.com/api/v3/company/profile/${symbol}`;
  fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      const profile = data.profile;
      companyTitle.textContent = profile.companyName;
      companyWebsite.textContent = profile.website;
      companyDescription.textContent = profile.description;
      price.textContent = "Stock Price: $" + profile.price;
      let profileChangesPercent = Number(profile.changesPercentage);

      if (profileChangesPercent >= 0) {
        changesPercentage.classList.add("green");
      } else if (profileChangesPercent < 0) {
        changesPercentage.classList.add("red");
      }
      changesPercentage.textContent = profileChangesPercent.toFixed(2) + "%";
      // set logo
      let img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = profile.image;
      companyLogo.appendChild(img);
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.warn("Something went wrong.", err.message);
    });
}
```

Comment: what do you want to show up as link? where's your html code? I don't understand what do you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change `companyWebsite.textContent = profile.website;` to `companyWebsite.innerHTML = "<a href='" + profile.website + "'>Hyperlink Text</a>"`

Comment: Awesome! I just needed the "<a href>" + profile.website + "</a>"; Thank you!